# select entire generic table but replace values with case

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I need to select an entire table but the values in 1 column.

Table1

```
user | replacement | other info
1    | a           | ok
2    | b           | hello
3    | c           | not ok
4    | a           | what
```

and I need

```
user | replacement | other info
1    | x           | ok
2    | y           | hello
3    | z           | not ok
4    | x           | what
```

I tried doing

```
select  *, 
        case replacement 
            when 'a' then 'x' 
            when 'b' then 'y' 
            when 'c' then 'z' 
from    table1
```

this almost works but

```
user | replacement | other info | case text
1    | a           | ok         | x
2    | b           | hello      | y
3    | c           | not ok     | z
4    | a           | what       | x
```

what can I do to instead overwrite the "replacement" column values? I need it to be generic to work on multiple tables with multiple names so I can't do "select user, case..., other info"

Comment: It is a new trend to make SQL generic. That is not how it works. Use specific queries.

Comment: You cannot do this via a generic `SELECT *` query.

Comment: That's not how the way you think it works.Avoid `SELECT * FROM table...` type query. Even in the case where you need all the columns.  I would suggest don't be pedantic on this.

Comment: " I can't do "select user, case..., other info" Why? (I have a feeling I'm not going to like this answer)

Comment: Probably one of those scientific libraries

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't realize it was bad sql style. So what if I were to write a script (not in sql) that would generate the sql using "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS" so I could just give it the table names and it would actually generate the sql correctly?